# How to send Perl Mail::Sender with mutated vowel?

Tags: perl, email

I have created a Perl script using Mail::Sender to send a mail. All fine - in general it works.

Some small problems.

The subject and the from name (name not e-mail address) include mutated vowels (German language special characters).

I have searched for some hints but did not find any.

Is there anywhere an example how to work with this or can someone please give me a hint how to get this done.

#### edit

I have done this:

```
ref ($av_tmp_MAIL = new Mail::Sender 
{ 
    from => "$av_loc_FROME ($av_loc_FROMN)",
    replyto => $av_loc_FROME,
    to => @av_loc_TO,
    cc => @av_loc_CC,
    bcc => @av_loc_BCC,
  smtp => 'smtp.av.loc',
}
)
 or die "Error($av_tmp_MAIL) : $Mail::Sender::Error\n";
```

When configuring the "from" part in the form "emailaddress (name)" you normally get the return in the mail client to have the senders name place before the senders e-Mail address in the form:

"name of sender <e-Mail address of sender>" where "<>" are really shown.

Since my senders name has some mutated vowels (German special characters) "Grundwasserfrühwarnsystem Forstinning" I need to encode this part.

I have tried all these variants:

```
#$av_loc_FROMN = Encode::encode("MIME-Q", Encode::decode_utf8($av_loc_FROMN)); # ganz seltsam mit der leerstelle
#$av_loc_FROMN = Encode::encode("MIME-Header", $av_loc_FROMN); # ganz seltsam mit der leerstelle
#$av_loc_FROMN = Encode::encode("MIME-Q", $av_loc_FROMN); # ganz schlecht
#$av_loc_FROMN = Encode::encode("MIME-B", $av_loc_FROMN); # tut es nicht
```

But they all do not do the trick.

To be honest - even when reading the doc, the differences between MIME-Q and MIME-B and MIME-Header are for sure a miracle for me. But I guess, I would need to study first x years to understand.

When using:

```
$av_loc_SUBJECT = Encode::encode("MIME-Q", Encode::decode_utf8($av_loc_SUBJECT));
```

For the SUBJECT of the mail - it works.

Text is "Funktionstest Grundwasserfrühwarnsystem Forstinning".

But in general, it should work with all kind of text.

#### edit

I will try to tell the whole story behind.

I have a Bash script doing the work. This works fine. But I have some problems in Bash to create a fine e-mail. Working with mailx works but also has some problems with codes. Working with sendmail is not easy from a bash script and also has some concerns with encoding. At least what I experienced.

My Bash script does some work and the result is written to a file by echo commands. The text of the file then has to be sent out in case of an alarm to some recipients.

The mail text file seems to be UTF-8-encoded and contains in some words these mutated vowels (Deutsche Umlaute).

I expected it to be easier with Perl to create a mail with more possibilities to format the e-mail (in HTML probably). So I wanted to create a Perl script to be called from the bash script with some positional parameters as handover like the from, to, cc, bcc, subject and the file where the text is already prepared.

That's what I am after.

And now I am figuring for a solution.

Yes, it is somehow production stuff (as you might imagine from the subject you saw). But it still is a private activity and some area to learn some programming in Perl, where I am a newbie in.

#### edit

This is not how it works; Settings of the parameters were the key to success but even some more prerequisites which had to be considered:

a) The perl script is called by a bash script.
b) The bash script naturally hands over the parameters (like --fromn). One of these parameters contains already accented vowels.
c) the bash script hands over the body to the perl script as a file. The perl script expects the file content to be encoded in utf8.

So far so good. But the major issue was: the bash script itself had to be a utf8-encoded file. Only then the handed over parameters and the body created by "echo"-commands used also utf8 to encode the character strings. !!!!!!!

Even setting the ENV to the correct language in the bash script did not help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;
use Net::Domain qw(hostname hostfqdn hostdomain domainname);
use Net::Ping;
use Getopt::Long;
use autodie; # die if problem reading or writing a file
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;
use feature qw{say};

use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;

use Mail::Sender;

use Log::Logger;






#  _      __        _       _     _      
#   \    / /       (_)     | |   | |     
#  \ \  / /_ _ _ __ _  __ _| |__ | | ___ 
#   \ \/ / _` | '__| |/ _` | '_ \| |/ _ \
#    \  / (_| | |  | | (_| | |_) | |  __/
#     \/ \__,_|_|  |_|\__,_|_.__/|_|\___|
#                                        
#                                        
### variables block
our $av_std_ARG=1;
our $av_std_BASE='';
our $av_std_BIN='/usr/local/share/averlon';
our $av_std_DEBUG=0;
our $av_std_DIRNAME=dirname(__FILE__); # gibt dann u.U. nur "." wieder
our $av_std_EXIT=0;
our $av_std_FORCE=0;
our $av_std_LOGFILE='/var/log/'.hostname().'.log';
our $av_std_LOGGING=0;
our $av_std_MESSAGEFILE='/usr/local/share/averlon/av_messages.xml';
our $av_std_POSPAR;
our $av_std_RETVAL;
our $av_std_STORAGE='/ourtmp/';
our $av_std_USER;
our $av_std_TEST=0;
our $av_std_TMP='/tmp/';
our $av_std_VERBOSE=0;
our $av_std_VERSION='01.0a';

our $av_loc_FROMN="";
our $av_loc_FROME="";
our $av_loc_TO="";
our @av_loc_TO=();
our $av_loc_CC="";
our @av_loc_CC=();
our $av_loc_BCC="";
our @av_loc_BCC=();
our $av_loc_SUBJECT;
our $av_loc_FBODY;
our $av_loc_FATT="";
our @av_loc_FATT=();

###
### predefined objects
###
our $av_tmp_DT=DateTime->today();
our $av_tmp_LOGFILE;
our $av_tmp_TMP;
our $av_tmp_MAIL;

our $av_tmp_STRING;
our $av_tmp_FN;
our $av_tmp_FILE;

#dialogelemente
my $av_WINDOW;
my $av_BUTTON;
my $av_HBOX;
my $av_VBOX;
my $av_TEXTBOX1;
my $av_LABEL1;

#  ______                _   _                 
#    ____|              | | (_)                
#   |__ _   _ _ __   ___| |_ _  ___  _ __  ___ 
#    __| | | | '_ \ / __| __| |/ _ \| '_ \/ __|
#   |  | |_| | | | | (__| |_| | (_) | | | \__ \
#  _|   \__,_|_| |_|\___|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|___/
#                                              
#                                              
### functions commands block

sub av_help
{
    print "Benutzung:\n";
    print "/usr/local/share/averlon/av_sendmail.pl [-d, --debug] [-f, --force] [-h, --help] [-l, --logging] [-t, --test] [-v, --verbose] [-V, --version]\n";
    print "[--fromn=<sender name>] [--frome=<e-mail>] [--to=<e-mail>[,<e-mail>]]\n";
    print "[--cc=<e-mail>[,<e-mail>]] [--bcc=<e-mail>[,<e-mail>]] [--subject=<subject>]\n";
    print "[--fbody=<filename of body>] [--fatt=<filename of attachment>[,<filename of attachment>]]\n";
    print "Bedeutung der Optionen:\n";
    print "  --fromn := Name of sender\n";
    print "  --frome := e-Mail address of sender\n";
    print "  --to := comma separated list of e-mail addresses to send to\n";
    print "  --cc := comma separated list of e-mail addresses for carbon copy\n";
    print "  --bcc := comma separated list of e-mail addresses for blind copy\n";
    print "  --subject := subject to show in mail\n";
    print "  --fbody := file which contains body text\n";
    print "  --fatt := list of filenames which to attach to e-Mail\n";
    print "  -d, --debug := debugging mode\n";
    print "  -f, --force := force running\n";
    print "\tforce will omit to check dates or other conditions\n";
    print "  -h, --help := diese Information\n";
    print "  -l, --logging := log all output to file in /var/userlog/\n";
    print "\tfile is stored in /var/userlog and will have job_ as prefix and .log as suffix\n";
    print "  -t, --test := test mode on\n";
    print "  -v, --verbose := verbose logging\n";
    print "  -V, --version := Version wird ausgegeben\n";
}

###
### routine für das logging
###
sub av_logit
{
    $av_tmp_STRING=DateTime->now(time_zone=>'Europe/Berlin')->strftime('%b')
    ." ".
    DateTime->now(time_zone=>'Europe/Berlin')->strftime('%d')
    ." ".
    DateTime->now(time_zone=>'Europe/Berlin')->strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    ." ".hostname()
    ." ";
    $av_tmp_LOGFILE->log("$av_tmp_STRING"."@_");
}
#  _____                                _   _             
#    __ \                              | | (_)            
#   |__) | __ ___ _ __   __ _ _ __ __ _| |_ _  ___  _ __  
#    ___/ '__/ _ \ '_ \ / _` | '__/ _` | __| |/ _ \| '_ \ 
#   |   | | |  __/ |_) | (_| | | | (_| | |_| | (_) | | | |
#  _|   |_|  \___| .__/ \__,_|_|  \__,_|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|
#                | |                                      
#                |_|                                      
### preparation commands block

GetOptions (
"fromn=s" => \$av_loc_FROMN,
"frome=s" => \$av_loc_FROME,
"to=s" => \$av_loc_TO,
"cc=s" => \$av_loc_CC,
"bcc=s" => \$av_loc_BCC,
"subject=s" => \$av_loc_SUBJECT,
"fbody=s" => \$av_loc_FBODY,
"fatt=s" => \$av_loc_FATT,
"d" => \$av_std_DEBUG,    # debug
"debug"   => \$av_std_DEBUG,      # debug
"f"   => \$av_std_FORCE,      # debug
"force"   => \$av_std_FORCE,      # debug
"h"   => \&av_help,      # help
"help"   => \&av_help,      # help
"l"   => \$av_std_LOGGING,      # logging
"logging"   => \$av_std_LOGGING,      # logging
"t"   => \$av_std_TEST,      # test
"test"   => \$av_std_TEST,      # test
"v"   => \$av_std_VERBOSE,      # verbose
"verbose"  => \$av_std_VERBOSE,   # verbose
"V"   => \$av_std_VERSION,      # version
"version"  => sub { say "Version: $av_std_VERSION" }    # version
)
or say ("Error in command line arguments: @ARGV");

###
### prepare logging
###
$av_tmp_LOGFILE=Log::Logger->new();
$av_tmp_LOGFILE->open_append("$av_std_LOGFILE");
&av_logit("gestartet");

$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_std_DEBUG: $av_std_DEBUG";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_std_FORCE: $av_std_FORCE";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_std_LOGGING: $av_std_LOGGING";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_std_TEST: $av_std_TEST";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_std_VERBOSE: $av_std_VERBOSE";

$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_FROMN: $av_loc_FROMN";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_FROME: $av_loc_FROME";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_TO: $av_loc_TO";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_CC: $av_loc_CC";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_BCC: $av_loc_BCC";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_SUBJECT: $av_loc_SUBJECT";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_FBODY: $av_loc_FBODY";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_FATT: $av_loc_FATT";

#  __  __       _         _____                  
#    \/  |     (_)       |  __ \                 
#   \  / | __ _ _ _ __   | |__) | __ ___   ___   
#   |\/| |/ _` | | '_ \  |  ___/ '__/ _ \ / __|  
#   |  | | (_| | | | | | | |   | | | (_) | (__ _ 
#  _|  |_|\__,_|_|_| |_| |_|   |_|  \___/ \___(_)
#                                                
#                                                
### main procedure

###
### prepare variables
###
if ($av_loc_TO) 
{
  $av_loc_TO =~s/ //u; # leerzeichen eleminieren
  push(@av_loc_TO,split(/,/,join(',',$av_loc_TO))); # hier werden die einzelnen einträge in ein array überführt; trennzeichen=,
  $av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_TO: @av_loc_TO";
  if ($#av_loc_TO >= 1) # wenn 1 oder mehr elemente im array vorhanden sind muss das array in einen komma-getrennten string überführt werden
  { 
    $av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_TO: @av_loc_TO";
    $av_std_DEBUG && print "$_"."\n" foreach (@av_loc_TO);
    $av_loc_TO=''; # string löschen
    foreach (@av_loc_TO)
    {
        $av_loc_TO=$_.",".$av_loc_TO; #elemente des array mit komma getrennt zusammenführen - vorsicht - zum schluss ist 1 komma zuviel
    }
    $av_loc_TO=substr($av_loc_TO,0,length($av_loc_TO)-1); # das letzte komma entfernen
  }
  else
  {
    $av_loc_TO=join(' ', @av_loc_TO);
  }
}
else
{
    # To darf nicht leer sein
    exit ($?+=2); # exit mit exit status gesetzt
}
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_TO: $av_loc_TO";


$av_loc_CC =~s/ //u; # leerzeichen eleminieren
push(@av_loc_CC,split(/,/,join(',',$av_loc_CC))); # hier werden die einzelnen einträge in ein array überführt; trennzeichen=,
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_CC: @av_loc_CC";
if ($#av_loc_CC >= 1) # wenn 1 oder mehr elemente im array vorhanden sind muss das array in einen komma-getrennten string überführt werden
{ 
    $av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_CC: @av_loc_CC";
    $av_std_DEBUG && print "$_"."\n" foreach (@av_loc_CC);
    $av_loc_CC=''; # string löschen
#   shift(@av_loc_CC);
    foreach (@av_loc_CC)
    {
        $av_loc_CC=$_.",".$av_loc_CC; #elemente des array mit komma getrennt zusammenführen - vorsicht - zum schluss ist 1 komma zuviel
    }
    $av_loc_CC=substr($av_loc_CC,0,length($av_loc_CC)-1); # das letzte komma entfernen
}
else
{
    $av_loc_CC=join(' ', @av_loc_CC);
}
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_CC: $av_loc_CC";


#@av_loc_BCC=('dummy@av.loc');
$av_loc_BCC =~s/ //u; # leerzeichen eleminieren
push(@av_loc_BCC, split(/,/,join(',',$av_loc_BCC))); # hier werden die einzelnen einträge in ein array überführt; trennzeichen=,
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_BCC: @av_loc_BCC";
if ($#av_loc_BCC >= 1) # wenn 1 oder mehr elemente im array vorhanden sind muss das array in einen komma-getrennten string überführt werden
{ 
    $av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_BCC: @av_loc_BCC";
    $av_std_DEBUG && print "$_"."\n" foreach (@av_loc_BCC);
    $av_loc_BCC=''; # string löschen
#   shift(@av_loc_BCC);
    foreach (@av_loc_BCC)
    {
        $av_loc_BCC=$_.",".$av_loc_BCC; #elemente des array mit komma getrennt zusammenführen - vorsicht - zum schluss ist 1 komma zuviel
    }
    $av_loc_BCC=substr($av_loc_BCC,0,length($av_loc_BCC)-1); # das letzte komma entfernen
}
else
{
    $av_loc_BCC=join(' ', @av_loc_BCC);
}
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_BCC: $av_loc_BCC";


#@av_loc_FATT=('dummy.txt');
$av_loc_FATT =~s/ //u; # leerzeichen eleminieren
push(@av_loc_FATT, split(/,/,join(',',$av_loc_FATT))); # hier werden die einzelnen einträge in ein array überführt; trennzeichen=,
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_FATT: @av_loc_FATT";
if ($#av_loc_FATT >= 1) # wenn 1 oder mehr elemente im array vorhanden sind muss das array in einen komma-getrennten string überführt werden
{ 
    $av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_FATT: @av_loc_FATT";
    $av_std_DEBUG && print "$_"."\n" foreach (@av_loc_FATT);
    $av_loc_FATT=''; # string löschen
#   shift(@av_loc_FATT);
    foreach (@av_loc_FATT)
    {
        $av_loc_FATT=$_.",".$av_loc_FATT; #elemente des array mit komma getrennt zusammenführen - vorsicht - zum schluss ist 1 komma zuviel
    }
    $av_loc_FATT=substr($av_loc_FATT,0,length($av_loc_FATT)-1); # das letzte komma entfernen
}
else
{
    $av_loc_FATT=join(' ', @av_loc_FATT);
}
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_FATT: $av_loc_FATT";

@av_loc_FATT=($av_loc_FATT);
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \@av_loc_FATT: @av_loc_FATT";
foreach $av_tmp_STRING (@av_loc_FATT)
{
  if ( !-f "$av_tmp_STRING" )
  {
    say "$av_tmp_STRING existiert nicht";
    exit ($?+=4);
  }
}

$Mail::Sender::NO_X_MAILER=1; # wichtig der unterdrückt eine meldung im header wo auf das skript rückschlüsse gezogen werden kann.

$av_loc_FROMN = Encode::encode("MIME-Q", Encode::decode('UTF-8', $av_loc_FROMN));
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_FROMN: $av_loc_FROMN";
$av_loc_SUBJECT = Encode::encode("MIME-Q", Encode::decode('utf8', $av_loc_SUBJECT));
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_SUBJECT: $av_loc_SUBJECT";

$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_TO: $av_loc_TO";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_CC: $av_loc_CC";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_BCC: $av_loc_BCC";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_FROMN: $av_loc_FROMN";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_FROME: $av_loc_FROME";
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$av_loc_SUBJECT: $av_loc_SUBJECT";


ref ($av_tmp_MAIL = new Mail::Sender 
{ 
    from => $av_loc_FROMN.'<'.$av_loc_FROME.'>',
    replyto => $av_loc_FROME,
    to => $av_loc_TO,
    cc => $av_loc_CC,
    bcc => $av_loc_BCC,
  smtp => 'smtp.av.loc',
}
) or $av_std_DEBUG && say "debug Return code $av_tmp_MAIL" and exit (1);
$av_std_DEBUG && $Mail::Sender::Error && say "\$Mail::Sender::Error: $Mail::Sender::Error" && exit (1);


$av_tmp_MAIL->OpenMultipart (
  {
    subject => $av_loc_SUBJECT,
    encoding => "Quoted-printable",
    multipart => 'Mixed',
    charset => 'UTF-8',
  }
);
$av_std_DEBUG && $Mail::Sender::Error && say "\$Mail::Sender::Error: $Mail::Sender::Error" && exit (1);


open(BODY, '<', "$av_loc_FBODY") || # zum Lesen geöffnet
  say "debug: Cannot open file $av_loc_FBODY for reading! error: $!" && exit (1);

$av_tmp_STRING='';
while(my $eingabe=<BODY>){
  chomp($eingabe);
  $av_tmp_STRING = $av_tmp_STRING.Encode::decode("UTF-8", $eingabe)."\r\n";
}
$av_std_DEBUG && say "$av_tmp_STRING";

close(BODY); 
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$ERRNO: $!";

$av_tmp_MAIL->Body (
  {
    charset => 'UTF-8',
    encoding => 'Quoted-printable',
    ctype => 'text/plain',
    msg => $av_tmp_STRING,
  }
);
$av_std_DEBUG && $Mail::Sender::Error && say "\$Mail::Sender::Error: $Mail::Sender::Error" && exit (1);
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$ERRNO: $!";


$av_tmp_MAIL->Attach(
{
    description => 'Grundwasser Statistikdaten',
  file => @av_loc_FATT,
}
);
$av_std_DEBUG && $Mail::Sender::Error && say "\$Mail::Sender::Error: $Mail::Sender::Error" && exit (1);
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$ERRNO: $!";

$av_tmp_MAIL->Close;
$av_std_DEBUG && $Mail::Sender::Error && say "\$Mail::Sender::Error: $Mail::Sender::Error" && exit (1);
$av_std_DEBUG && say "debug \$ERRNO: $!";

#  ______           _   _____                  
# |  ____|         | | |  __ \                 
# | |__   _ __   __| | | |__) | __ ___   ___   
# |  __| | '_ \ / _` | |  ___/ '__/ _ \ / __|  
# | |____| | | | (_| | | |   | | | (_) | (__ _ 
# |______|_| |_|\__,_| |_|   |_|  \___/ \___(_)
#                                              
#                                              
### end procedure
&av_logit("beendet");
exit (0);
```

Comment: Seems like an encoding problem!!!

Comment: See [Encode::MIME::Header](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::MIME::Header) or [Email::MIME::RFC2047](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME::RFC2047).

Comment: "Mutated" is a really odd term. You'll have better luck with Google if you use "accented"; even the German "umlaut" is widely understood in English discussions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the solution that works for you, it seems that your input variables are encoded UTF-8 strings. That's why you have to decode them first. This might be a problem in itself, but it's impossible to judge without knowing the rest of your code.

To convert strings encoded as UTF-8 to MIME header encoding, the [`from_to` function](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode#from_to) is a bit simpler than your solution:

```
# Re-encodes $av_loc_FROMN in place.
Encode::from_to($av_loc_FROMN, "UTF-8", "MIME-Header");
```

As mentioned by @Andrzej, you should consider the MIME-Q encoding. With MIME-Q, your encoded email headers stay human-readable for the most part. It really shouldn't make any difference whether you use "MIME-Header" (effectively "MIME-B") or "MIME-Q", so I'm puzzled why your attempt

```
$av_loc_FROMN = Encode::encode("MIME-Q", Encode::decode_utf8($av_loc_FROMN)); # ganz seltsam mit der leerstelle
```

didn't work. Older versions of the `Encode` distribution had numerous bugs concerning MIME header encoding, though. Maybe you're running into one of them.

If you're really interested in the correctness of your code, I also wouldn't recommend `Encode::MIME::Header` for mail headers containing RFC 2822 "mailboxes" and "phrases", like From, To, Cc, Reply-To, etc. That's because this module doesn't touch characters like `<`, `"`, or `@`, all of which can have a special meaning in this context and should be quoted. In general, `Encode::MIME::Header` is only safe for Subject headers, or for display names that contain only alphanumeric characters. For robust handling of mailboxes, I recommend [`Email::MIME::RFC2047`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME::RFC2047). (Disclosure: I'm the author of this distribution.)

Comment: the version with MIME-Q worked in general but had a courious effect. The input string was "Grundwasserfrühwarnsystem Forstinning" and the result was "Grundwasserfrühwarns" "stem Forstinning" <noreply@example.de>
You see - somehow courious. So I dismissed it.

Comment: I have meanwhile tested several modules. I will give it a try with the one you recommended. Charsets and codes are a difficult are and, I guess, only transparent for specialists. I am not one at all!

Answer (score -1):

Me gain!

this is the result which works - don't ask me why!

```
$av_loc_FROMN = Encode::encode("MIME-Header", Encode::decode_utf8($av_loc_FROMN));
```

Regards

Karl-Heinz

Comment: Which locale do you use? (See LANG environment variable) Is it UTF-8 based?) Do you use `use utf8;` in your scripts?

Comment: BTW In "mostly ascii" languages (like German) it makes sence to force `MIME-Q` encoding - it leaves headers "mostly readable" in raw format.

Comment: @Andrzej: this is the environment my server runs with:

locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de:en
LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=